# How can I disable software update notifications in kde/plasma

Tags: kde, popups, automatic-update, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

I keep getting popups about updates and it's annoying. The window below is from the taskbar icon settings that I think is causing the popup. Is there a workaround? If I knew which package was the culprit maybe I could uninstall it.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know for other distros, but for Fedora

```
dnf remove plasma-pk-updates
```

should solve it.

Comment: As of Fedora 34, this package has changed to be called plasma-discover-notifier. If I remember correctly, this is because the notification has been moved from the separate plasmoid into Discover (the Plasma software center)

Comment: it didn't solve my issue .. it wasn't installed ... I am using Fedora 35

Comment: @MdFaisal for fedora 35 see my answer https://superuser.com/a/1707086/197111

Comment: Thanks @Trismegistos I will come to this when I will use Fedora KDE again... I was so annoyed by this that I circled back to Ubuntu .. and I kind of like it for now at least..

Answer (score 12):

Go to Panel settings:

[image: Panel settings]

Then go to System tray settings:

[image: System tray settings]

Comment: What's with the downvotes? This worked for me, and is distribution-agnostic, unlike the accepted answer.

Comment: @RyanLue because it didn't work for them maybe? The other answer is pretty agnostic, albeit you can't apply it verbatim. Just propose an edit that appends the equivalent package name and `pacman`/`apt-get` command for your distro to the answer and it'll then work as-is for others without them needing to put in any effort.

Comment: I assume this awnser as more precise as the accepted one, because remove the package for the complete system may be a solution for a single user environment, but with a system with multiple users I just want to disable this notifier for non sudo users and I want the admins to kept informed.

Comment: I didn't have these many options in General settings.. so this didn't solve my issue.. I am using Fedora 35 KDE

Answer (score 1):

for fedora 35

```
dnf remove plasma-discover-notifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just End "Discover-notifier" process from system-monitor, although this needs to do it everytime u boot.